# return array that indicates a negative accumulation quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

I have a javascript function that loops through an INPUT array (argument) in order to mutate a GLOBAL array (insert, replace, or delete) and it returns a RETURN array whose length represents accumulation change rate of mutation confirmations.

For example:

- if there are three inserts, then the RETURN array is [true, true,
  true] -> change rate length == 3
- if there are three inserts and one delete, then the RETURN array
  is [true, true]  -> change rate length == 2
- if there are three inserts and a replace, then the RETURN array is
  [true, true, true]  -> change rate length == 3
- if there are three inserts, a replace, and one delete, then the
  RETURN array is [true, true]  -> change rate length == 2
- if there are three replaces, the the RETURN array is [ ]  -> change
  rate length == 0

I am having trouble with these two scenarios:

- if there are two inserts and three deletes ... change rate length == -1
- if there are three deletes ... change rate length == -3

Is there a weird way for an array to indicate negative length? I really don't want the caller to have to loop through and validate.

My initial thought is to use the zero index (or a separate, additional return variable) as a flag to indicate positive, neutral, or negative change rate accumulation length but implementing this way requires more code and additional complexity.

Ideally what I'd really want is the ability to put a + or a - in front of the array (maybe serialize this and then let the caller eval) but I am wondering if there is a better way?

Many thanks in advance for help you can offer.

Comment: It seems as though you're abusing the array construct. What you want is a numeric return, why are you not using one?

Comment: bc the return is a result of Observable.forkJoin( ... )

Comment: You cannot have `-ve` length in array, but you can change logic to return `[false, false]` for negative length. So have 2 counters, `insert`, `delete`, and you can try something like `var a = new Array(Math.abs(insert + del)).fill(insert+del>0?true: false)`

Comment: thanks - I ended up just making a proxy function in between caller and the forkjoin. That allowed me to take a snapshot of the GLOBAL array length before and after the forkjoin